# Queue-triggered Azure Function finishes successfully but throws error at end

Tags: azure-functions

my queue-triggered functions shows odd behaviour. After triggering it completes successfully a few minutes later.

`[09.09.2020 15:46:16] Executed 'CalculateStuff' (Succeeded, Id=c56f689a-0a56-4bcf-85ca-080cbbc2b6d0)`

About 1 minute after this line the function app apparently throws an error because in the terminal (when running locally) it displays the hint that the message has been moved to the -poison queue because MaxDequeueCount of 1 has been reached.

`[09.09.2020 15:47:03] Message has reached MaxDequeueCount of 1. Moving message to queue 'queue-name-poison'.`

I explicitly chose this to be 1 (default is 5) because part of the function's internals uploads a request to an external sftp server and then polls for a reply., which can take up to 5mins. If MaxDequeueCount is > 1 and there is an error this process takes place more than once which is not what I want.

However what puzzles me is that the functions itself finishes successfully and the end somehow still throws an exception. I don't know where this is coming from. Do you have any ideas why this is?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```html
Hosting environment: Development
Content root path: C:\Users\name\source\functionApp\bin\output
Now listening on: http://0.0.0.0:7071
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.

Http Functions:

        Starter: [POST] http://localhost:7071/api/sl2/new

[09.09.2020 15:40:42] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '00000000000000000000000041CA841C'.
[09.09.2020 15:40:48] Executing HTTP request: {
[09.09.2020 15:40:48]   "requestId": "732c5eed-8e45-46e0-9760-bcbd91ecdbee",
[09.09.2020 15:40:48]   "method": "POST",
[09.09.2020 15:40:48]   "uri": "/api/sl2/new"
[09.09.2020 15:40:48] }
[09.09.2020 15:40:48] Executing 'Starter' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=87b75e56-1a2e-4344-867e-fb3f063143d4)
[09.09.2020 15:40:48] Executed 'Starter' (Succeeded, Id=87b75e56-1a2e-4344-867e-fb3f063143d4)
[09.09.2020 15:40:48] Executed HTTP request: {
[09.09.2020 15:40:48]   "requestId": "732c5eed-8e45-46e0-9760-bcbd91ecdbee",
[09.09.2020 15:40:48]   "method": "POST",
[09.09.2020 15:40:48]   "uri": "/api/sl2/new",
[09.09.2020 15:40:48]   "identities": [
[09.09.2020 15:40:48]     {
[09.09.2020 15:40:48]       "type": "WebJobsAuthLevel",
[09.09.2020 15:40:48]       "level": "Admin"
[09.09.2020 15:40:48]     }
[09.09.2020 15:40:48]   ],
[09.09.2020 15:40:48]   "status": 202,
[09.09.2020 15:40:48]   "duration": 171
[09.09.2020 15:40:48] }
[09.09.2020 15:40:52] Executing 'CalculateStuff' (Reason='New queue message detected on 'queue-name'.', Id=c56f689a-0a56-4bcf-85ca-080cbbc2b6d0)
[09.09.2020 15:40:52] Trigger Details: MessageId: 630fc042-f61d-4fc2-9dae-c5b22092db14, DequeueCount: 1, InsertionTime: 09.09.2020 15:40:48 +00:00
....
[09.09.2020 15:46:16] Executed 'CalculateStuff' (Succeeded, Id=c56f689a-0a56-4bcf-85ca-080cbbc2b6d0)
[09.09.2020 15:47:03] Message has reached MaxDequeueCount of 1. Moving message to queue 'queue-name-poison'.
```

Comment: Can you share a bit of your code?  From the logs it looks like you've got an async function that starts at main... calls another async method and doesn't await it.  So, the main thread completes `Executed 'CalculateStuff'` while the background thread is still executing and eventually errors `Message has reached MaxDequeueCount of 1. Moving message to queue 'queue-name-poison'. `    This could be an async thing, but need to see a bit more code to be sure.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Unfortunately the code quiete long and I cannot reproduce it here in full. There are 12 async operations included and I'm certain that all are awaited properly. Subsequent invocations don't show the problem I described above, so I really cannot reproduce the error.

Comment: Going off of logs only, when I see a function complete and then an exception is thrown, I usually suspect an incorrectly awaited or async void background thread.  But you've clearly explained it can't be that.  At this point, I'm afraid I am of no use to you.  I require code samples to help people troubleshoot code.  Wishing you the best of luck solving the puzzle.